# Android & RoboGuice - Inject views on Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, inject, roboguice

I have a fragment that I need to display on the screen. I want to be able to use `InjectView` to inject my UI elements. InjectView works fine on activities because the view (xml) is set during `onCreate`, however on fragments the view is set on `onCreatView`.

So is there a way to use InjectView on fragments? I know that I could use findViewbyId to find each element, but I rather use InjectView

```
public class ProfileFragment extends RoboDialogFragment {

    @InjectView(R.id.commentEditText)
    protected EditText commentEditText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // I get a  null pointer exception here
            commentEditText.setText("Some comment");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile , container, false);

            // I get a  null pointer exception here
        commentEditText.setText("Some comment");

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please star the Roboguice issue (http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/issues/detail?id=160&q=contentview) to show the developers this should be added

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Injection happens during `onViewCreated`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    commentEditText.setText("Some comment");
}
```

Comment: we'll work on getting better docs for 2.0 now that it's in release candidate

Comment: @emmby Any luck with the docs? It's been released for a minute now, and the docs are still lacking, at least for a good and thorough example of Fragments.

Comment: we're working on the docs now.  they're getting better, but still not there yet:  https://github.com/emmby/roboguice/wiki

Comment: @emmby it's been 2 and a half years and this very basic and common idiom in roboguice is still not documented!

Comment: Hah! Good point, done: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Your-First-View-Injection