# Start Activity within a fragment

Tags: android, button, android-activity, fragment, onclicklistener

I'm trying to start a new Tab1City activity, as I click on a button from Tab1Discover, which is a fragment.
I've try several combinaisons if parameters, looking on stackoverflow, but it keeps compiling and making the app crash at launch, with a :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

at Tab1Discover.onCreateView(Tab1Discover.java:32)

```
public class Tab1Discover extends Fragment {

@InjectView(R.id.buttonLille)
Button _loginButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start the Signup activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Tab1City.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1_disc1_main, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

I've noticed (thanks to the comment) that you're using RoboGuice. After a [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9780769/3249477), I've come up that the reference will only be available in `onViewCreated`, so move your code there:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1_disc1_main, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // Start the Signup activity
      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Tab1City.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: His `@InjectView (R.id.idhere) CLASS varname;` is perfectly valid. Shouldn't he still inflate the xml before using the variable if he uses `@InjectView`? If not, then it could simply be that `R.id.buttonLille` isn't existent.

Comment: @showp1984 thanks for the insight. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Android Studio says to me that types are incompatibles, as _loginButton is a button, and it found that R.id.buttonLille is a view

Comment: @AdrienChapelet you will need RoboGuice if you are going to use `@InjectView`. See: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/

Comment: @AdrienChapelet if you're talking about my old answer, you need to cast it using `... = (Button) ...`

Answer (score 0):

From your usage of '@InjectView', i'm guessing you're using ButterKnife 6.0.x.

You're missing the part of ButterKnife where you have to tell it WHEN to inject the views.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1_disc1_main, container, false);

    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

    _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start the Signup activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Tab1City.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

With this code, you're telling ButterKnife where to find the view so it can set up the bindings. From here on, you can simply add all the @InjectView you want, and it'll take care of the bindings automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, that's now working :

```
public class Tab1Discover extends Fragment {

@InjectView(R.id.buttonLille)
Button _lilleButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1_disc1_main, container, false);

    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);

    _lilleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start the Signup activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Tab1City.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```